# Print make_request content

Tags: python, python-2.x

```
import urllib, urllib2, json
def make_request(method, base, path, params):
    if method == 'GET':
        return json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(base+path+"?"+urllib.urlencode(params)).read())
    elif method == 'POST':
        return json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(base+path, urllib.urlencode(params)).read())
api_key = "5f1d5cb35cac44d3b"
print make_request("GET", "https://indit.ca/api/", "v1/version", {"api_key": api_key})
```

This set of code returns should return back the version and status like {status: 'ok', version: '1.1.0'}

What code do I need to add to print that response ?

Comment: So what are you getting returned?

Comment: I'm not getting anything.It's just blank.

Comment: your code looks correct, and if you're running interactively you don't even need that print after `make_request()`, when I run your code I do get a response (it is a Errno 10061 refusal error, but a response no the less) and it is printed out.

Comment: I'm not getting anything.no error message no response.Just blank.When I hit enter it takes me to >>>>

Comment: Why is this tagged both `python-3.x` and `python-2.x`? In 3.x, this is just going to get an `ImportError` on the first line, which doesn't seem too relevant to the problem…

Comment: @Mike: You're actually getting a response back with that error in it? Because I get a `URLError` exception raised by the `urlopen` call (errno 8 on Unix, 10061 on Windows) before it even gets that far.

Comment: @abarnert - I got the 10061 on Windows (didn't try Linux), the full message was `urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>`, I guess to me that sounded like it correctly "reached out" but was rejected by the remote server (probably because it's a secure connection and some credentials were wrong). Am I misreading that error message?

Comment: @Mike: So you got an exception, not a return value, and it's not even getting to execute the `print`, right? If so, that's the same thing I'm getting.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what the problem is without a [complete, otherwise-working example](http://sscce.org) (I can't even resolve host `indit.ca`), but I can explain how you can debug this yourself. Break it down step by step:

```
import urllib, urllib2, json
def make_request(method, base, path, params):
    if method == 'GET':
        url = base+path+"?"+urllib.urlencode(params)
        print 'url={}'.format(url)
        req = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        print 'req={}'.format(req)
        body = req.read()
        print 'body={}'.format(body)
        obj = json.loads(body)
        print 'obj={}'.format(obj)
        return obj
    elif method == 'POST':
        # You could do the same here, but your test only uses "GET"
        return json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(base+path, urllib.urlencode(params)).read())

api_key = "5f1d5cb35cac44d3b"
print make_request("GET", "https://indit.ca/api/", "v1/version", {"api_key": api_key})
```

Now you can see where it goes wrong. Is it generating the right URL? (What happens if you paste that URL into a browser address bar, or a `wget` or `curl` command line?) Does `urlopen` return the kind of object you expected? Does the body look right? And so on.

Ideally, this will solve the problem for you. If not, at least you'll have a much more specific question to ask, and are much more likely to get a useful answer.